# WordCount in Java

Tags: java, word-count

I am practicing some exercises for my CS final, and am stuck on this problem, where I have to read a string, get a minimum length from the user, and return the amount of words that have at least that many letters. It seems as if my code is fine, but it can't print out the answer. Can anyone help me out?

```
public class WordCount {



    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a string: "); 
        String input =  IO.readString();


        System.out.println("Enter minimum word length");
        int wordlength = IO.readInt();
        int count = 0 ;
        do  {

            for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length(); i ++) {

                if (input.indexOf(i) == ' ') {

                    String check = input.substring(0, i);
                    if (check.length() >= wordlength) {

                        count++;
                        input = input.substring(i);
                        break;

                    }
                }

                    }

        } while (input.length() > 0);


    System.out.print("Words longer than " + wordlength + " characters: " + count);

    }

}
```

It seems as if the while loop runs infinitely, but I can't figure out why!

Comment: Are you sure that you want `input.indexOf(i)` ? I'm note sure how that fits in with the logic. I think you want `input[i]`

Comment: Is it sure that your string will have space separated words?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to split the input string and then count the Strings that are larger than your value?

Comment: @miketheLiar, I think you are right, since index of only returns an int value.

Comment: Are you restricted in what classes you can use? Your problem would be made much easier with the use of a `StringTokenizer`.

Comment: @Robert, not really sure how the split command works, and I'm trying to make sure that the logic of my loops is right before learning other methods.

Comment: Simply split your incoming string into a string array and then compare the length of each element with your input number.. for information on split command look here - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are few problems with your code that I'll point out first: -

```
if (input.indexOf(i) == ' ')
```

In the above statement, you should use `String#charAt` method, to get a character at a particular index. `String#indexOf` method is used for reverse process, i.e, you have a character and you want to find it's index.

Secondly, you are modifying your `input` inside the `loop itself`. And you are using the length of `input` in the terminating condition in the `loop`. You should not do anything like this. 
Rather, you can use another variable, which will store the index of last word you processed. And use that `index` in your `substring` method.

Thirdly, you don't really need a `do while` loop here. Your `for loop` itself is iterating over all your characters. Just remove the `break` from your `if`, which is really not required.

So, your code will be modified to this: -

```
int oldIndex = 0;  // to maintain the end index of previous word.
int length = input.length();
for (int i = 0 ; i < length; i ++) {

          if (input.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == length - 1) {

                // If the word is at the end, then probably your first 
                // condition in above `if` would fail, that is why I used a 
                // second condition, which checks the end of string

                // Now for the end of the string, we would need to use a single
                // arguement substring method to get the word till the end.
                // hence the below conditional expression.

                String check = (i == length - 1)? input.substring(oldIndex): 
                                                input.substring(oldIndex, i);

                oldIndex = i + 1;  // Set oldIndex to the next index.

                if (check.length() >= wordlength) {

                    count++;
                    //  input = input.substring(i);  Don't do this
                    // break;   // Don't break too.

                }
           }

}
```

---

Now this was the modification of your code, so that you can learn what was your mistake.

However, you have a pretty easy way to get what you want. You can use `String#split` method to `split` your string on `space`, which will return you an array of all the words, and you can operate on those words.

It works something like this (in case you can use it): -

```
String[] words = input.split(" ");  // split input string on space

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  // iterate over array
    if (words[i].length() >= wordLength) {
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly does this do:

 String check = (i == length - 1)? input.substring(oldIndex): 
                                                  input.substring(oldIndex, i); 

Particularly, what does the '?' operator do?

Comment: Actually I think I got it. Is that just basically a conditional that continues with the command on the rest of the line if true, and goes to the condition on the next line if false?

Answer (score 3):

I will simply use split as below:

```
    System.out.println("Enter minimum word length");
    int wordlength = IO.readInt();
    int count = 0 ;
    //get all words in string array by splitting the input around space
    String[] words = input.split(" ");//assuming words are separated by space

    //now iterate the words, check the length, if word is of desired length or more
    //increase the word counter
    for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length; i ++) {
       if (words[i].length() >= wordlength) {
         count++;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Since OP is a `CS` student, you should probably first solve the issue using his method. Of course `split` is a better way to go. But again, that does not help OP learn why his code didn't work.

Comment: It's not that complex which needs explanations. I added inline comments any way.

Comment: Wow, why the hell wasn't I taught this in the first place lol. Thanks.

Comment: @PavelVaysberg: If you this this is helpful then don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `do-while` loop runs indefinitely because that's what's you've set it up to do. Let's simplify this:

```
string input = "this is an example string";
do
{
     //some logic
     if (input.indexOf(i) == ' ') // this never executes - indexOf(i) returns an int
     {
          //do some stuff with input
     }

}
while (input.length() > 0);
```

`input.length()` is **always** greater than zero. The block which alters `input` never executes, so `input` stays the same, and the length of the string `input` is always greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `indexOf(i)` you need to use `charAt(i)` to retrieve the character at position `i`, the loop and logic look OK for the purpose stated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the javadoc for substring.  It starts at the index you give it and is inclusive.  So your substring call is always going to give you a string with a length of at least one.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex)
Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.

Examples:

     "unhappy".substring(2) returns "happy"
     "Harbison".substring(3) returns "bison"
     "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)


Parameters:
    beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive. 
Returns:
    the specified substring. 
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.
```

Try something like this:

```
String input = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten";
    int minLength = 4;
    int count = 0;
    String[] strings = input.split(" ");
    for(String s : strings) {
        if(s.length() >= minLength) {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
```